# how to map parent class including their nested children

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, ienumerable, icollection

If I have two classes like this :

1-ParentViewModel:

```
   public class ParentViewModel
        {
            public Guid Id { get;  set; }
            public string Name { get;  set; }
            public IList<ChildViewModel> Children { get; set; }

        }
```

---

2- ChildViewModel

```
public class ChildViewModel
    {
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Guid? ParentViewModelId { get;  set; }

    }
```

---

And I have two domain models the parent equivalent contains:
`Icollection<Child>` instead of `IList<ChildViewModel>`

I want to map from the parent view model to the parent domain (including the mapping of children)  and vice versa from the domain to view model including the nested children?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just manually/tediously map the properties, but, if you want a more general solution, you can use reflection to map properties by name and handle the special case for collections.

*Notes:
1. This will fail for properties that are interface collection types, but you could adjust the code slightly to handle that.
2. Error handling has not been added 
3. This attempts to map properties by name, so domain class and view model class must have same prop names.
4. It will skip the properties it doesn't find on the destination class

```
public class ObjectMapper
{

    public void MapObject(object source, object destination)
    {

        var srcType = source.GetType();//get source type
        var srcProps = srcType.GetProperties();//get src props, supply appropriate binding flags
        var destType = destination.GetType();//get dest type
        var destProps = destType.GetProperties();//get dest props, supply appropriate binding flags

        foreach (var prop in srcProps)
        {
            //find corresponding prop on dest obj
            var destProp = destProps.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == prop.Name);
            //only map if found on dest obj
            if (destProp != null)
            {
                //get src value
                var srcVal = prop.GetValue(source);
                //get src prop type
                var propType = prop.PropertyType;
                //get dest prop type
                var destPropType = destProp.PropertyType;

                //special case for collections
                if (typeof(IList).IsAssignableFrom(propType))
                {
                    //instantiate dest collection
                    var newCollection = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(destPropType);
                    //get source collection
                    var collection = (IList)srcVal;
                    //get dest collection element type
                    var elementType = destPropType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();

                    //iterate collection
                    foreach (var element in collection)
                    {
                        //instantiate element type 
                        var tempElement = Activator.CreateInstance(elementType);
                        //call map object on each element
                        MapObject(source: element, destination: tempElement);
                        //add mapped object to new collection
                        newCollection.Add(tempElement);
                    }

                    //set dest object prop to collection
                    destProp.SetValue(destination, newCollection);
                }
                else
                {
                    destProp.SetValue(destination, srcVal);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```